# Dynamically pass ARM parameter as customscriptextension parameter

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-vm-templates

I would like to run a PowerShell custom script inside arm template, so it sets port forwarding and set firewall, script is as following

```
function set-proxy {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True, HelpMessage = "proxy informations")]
        [hashtable[]]$proxyinfos
    )
    
    foreach ($proxyinfo in $proxyinfos){
    netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=$($proxyinfo.listenaddress) `
    listenport=$($proxyinfo.listenport) connectaddress=$($proxyinfo.connectaddress) connectport=$($proxyinfo.connectport)
    }
}

function set-firewall {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True, HelpMessage = "proxy informations")]
        [hashtable[]]$proxyinfos
    )
    
    foreach ($proxyinfo in $proxyinfos){
        New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $($proxyinfo.firewallrulename) -Direction $($proxyinfo.direction) `
        -LocalPort $($proxyinfo.listenport) -Protocol $($proxyinfo.protocol) -Action $($proxyinfo.action)
    }
}

set-proxy $proxyinfos
set-firewall $proxyinfos
```

I'm hoping the proxyinfo can be passed as an array of hashtable

```
$proxyinfos=@(
    @{
        listenaddress="10.1.10.20"
        listenport="443"
        connectaddress="10.1.10.20"
        connectport="443"
        firewallrulename= "port443"
        direction="Inbound"
        action="Allow"
        protocol="TCP"
    },
    @{
        listenaddress="10.1.10.20"
        listenport="80"
        connectaddress="10.1.10.20"
        connectport="80"
        firewallrulename= "port80"
        direction="Inbound"
        action="Allow"
        protocol="TCP"
    }
)
```

But I'm a bit stuck trying to see how I can pass it from arm template parameter file.

If I create an array parameter called proxyinfos

```
"proxyinfos": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "listenaddress": "10.1.10.20",
                    "listenport": "443",
                    "connectaddress": "10.1.10.20",
                    "connectport": "443",
                    "firewallrulename": "port443",
                    "direction": "Inbound",
                    "action": "Allow",
                    "protocol": "TCP"
                },
                {
                    "listenaddress": "10.1.10.20",
                    "listenport": "80",
                    "connectaddress": "10.1.10.20",
                    "connectport": "80",
                    "firewallrulename": "port80",
                    "direction": "Inbound",
                    "action": "Allow",
                    "protocol": "TCP"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: You can refer to [Custom Script Extension Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#extension-schema), [Pass parameters to Custom Script Extension script using ARM templates](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41c1027e-bc5d-4de8-a663-45aa84357728/pass-parameters-to-custom-script-extension-script-using-arm-templates) and [Creating Dynamic Azure ARM Templates](https://adamcook.io/p/creating-dynamic-azure-arm-templates/)

Answer (score 1):

got it working in the end
when passing paramater, gotta do this

```
"commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file configure-portforwarding.ps1 -proxyinfosjson ', string(parameters('proxyinfos')))]"
```

so when passing this paramater to powershell, the json looks something like this

```
[{"listenaddress":"10.1.10.20","listenport":"443","connectaddress":"10.1.10.20","connectport":"443","firewallrulename":"port443","direction":"Inbound","action":"Allow 
","protocol":"TCP"},{"listenaddress":"10.1.10.20","listenport":"80","connectaddress":"10.1.10.20","connectport":"80","firewallrulename":"port80","direction":"Inbound","action":"Allow","protocol":"TCP"}]
```

and inside powershell

```
$proxyinfos= ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $proxyinfosjson
```